# java step by step compile / execute / debug

Tags: java, debugging, execution, execute

I have a small piece of code where I would like to know how the debugger thinks.

```
/**L05*/ public class Main {
/**L06*/ public static void sp(String a){
/**L07*/    System.out.println(a);
/**L08*/ }
/**L09*/
/**L10*/ public static void main(String[] args) {
/**L11*/    sp("start");
/**L12*/
/**L13*/    //object-1
/**L14*/    Player p1 = new Player();
/**L15*/    sp("p1");
/**L16*/
/**L17*/    //object-2
/**L18*/    Player
/**L19*/            p2
/**L20*/            =
/**L21*/            new
/**L22*/                    Player
/**L23*/                    (
/**L24*/                    )
/**L25*/            ;
/**L26*/    sp
/**L27*/            (
/**L28*/                    "p2"
/**L29*/            )
/**L30*/    ;
/**L31*/
/**L32*/    //object-3
/**L33*/    Player p3= new Player(){/**strange that this works*/};
/**L34*/    Player p4=
/**L35*/    new Player();
/**L36*/    Player p5;
/**L37*/  }
/**L38*/ }
```

[code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e50eW.png)

**I would like to know the execution process from Line 18 till 30.**

For example when I debug the code (starting now from Line 11) it goes step by step so:

***Line11***
There it executes the method and after that it goes to

***Line13*** 
because it is an comment. It do not execute it and then goes to

***Line 14***
there it makes an object of the Player -> reserves space how much Player needs. 
Calls the default-Constructor
gives and reference (pointer named as p1) the type of Player and puts the Playerobject into the Player. Endofline now it goes to

***Line 15***
it executes. Now it goes to

***Line 17***
its a comment and then it goes to

***Line 18***
"?" now i get confused. When i debug the code 
-> it goes after Line 17 to Line 19 and not to Line 18 or to Line 21
or how i long time thought the compiler starts from the right side from Semicolon and goes from right to left.

After ***Line19*** it skips the other lines and goes to

***Line 26***
strange -> where are the lines 18,22-25 when do it execute this lines.
And how/when would the debugger recognizes when i have forgot an semicolon on Line25 ?

I have debugged my code step by step with breakpoints.
The output is ok and fine.
The code Player.java file is not important for this question.
If there is something missing or not understandable please tell me and I can add or change it.

Comment: Please include the code itself in the question

Comment: Could you put yor code here, instead of linking?

Answer (score 1):

The debugger doesn't see those lines per se because nothing interesting happens on those lines.

Line 18 is a type declaration, p2 on line 19 is interesting because there the reference value for p2 is allocated and assigned the value after the =.

Then it skips to the next execution and that's line 26.

You spread it out over the multiple lines, but the debugger runs off compiled code, that has certain "hooks" in them that point to the position in the original source code.

Normally you'd code this in a single line, and that's how the debuggers are set up. If you wish to see more details use the step into option instead of step over.

Basically a debugger shows you points in the code where things change and states get updated. When the debugger is paused on those lines you can check what values of variables are and the state of objects, etc... 
It does not see any other things or artifacts in the code you've introduced, only when new things are created, values assigned or changed. Only the interesting stuff, at the point where it happens, so you can analyze values that are passed on to a method, values returned from a method, a new instantiated class state, etc... to see if everything is right as rain.

Ask yourself, `what value would I gain if the debugger paused on line 24?` *Absolutely nothing.* The interesting part happens right before `p2` is assigned and after `p2` is assigned, or in the constructor of `Player()` for which you can choose step into, or when an `Exception` is thrown.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. I did the Step-into with debugger "F7" But i would like to know it the debugger makes the left-side of the "=" first or the right side of the "=" first. It seems so that the whole "new" line from 21-44 get skipped. And when that get skipped it can not be executed.

Comment: @not_null if you use step into you notice when it jumps into the public Player(){} method. Try assigning a value to a property within the constructor. Then see when it steps into the constructor, before or after p2 is assigned

Comment: i have add the Lines 34-36 where the Line 35 should get executed. When i do not execute the Line 35 how the code can make an object?

Comment: Ok seems it be so that: Line34-> 1st it makes an reference to the whole class. 2nd it see the "=" and executes the what is on the right side from "=" (that is to call the new constructor and make the object. 3rd no p4 gets this object.  //but what happens then on line 36? It do not get an object but get an reference to the  class?

Comment: @not_null on line 36 you're reserving space in RAM for an instance of Player. It's not occupied there yet, but it is as if you put a sign on a parking spot: Only parking for xyz. That memory space will stay reserved for the duration of the scope.